# C++ Password attempt limit

Tags: c++, passwords, login-attempts

Im trying to write a program that limits the password to three incorrect attempts then exits after 3 incorrect attempts. Here is the code I have thus far. I feel like I am really close to figuring this out but i cannot figure out what to do.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void getPassword() 
{ 
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    string password; 
    cout << "Enter the password: "; 
    getline(cin, password); 

    if (password == "12345") break; 
      cout << "INVALID. "; 
  } //for
} // getPassword 
int main ()
{
  if (!getPassword()) break;
  else break;
  cout <<endl; 

  ofstream fout; 
  fout.open("mort.txt", ios::app);
  if (!fout.good()) throw "I/O error";

  double p; //Principal/Mortgage Amount
  cout << "What's the mortgage amount?";
  cin >> p; 
  cin.ignore (1000, 10);

  double r; 
  cout << "What's the annual interest rate?";
  cin >> r ;
  cin.ignore (1000, 10);
  double a = r / 100;
  double i = a / 12;

  double n = 30 * 12; //Number of payments per month
  double t = (p*(pow (1+i, n))*i) / ((pow(1+i, n)) -1);// monthly payment formula 

  cout<< fixed;
  cout<< setprecision(2);

  cout << "Mortgage Amount: "<<"$"<< p <<endl;
  cout << "Interest Rate: "<< r <<"%"<<endl;
  cout << "Term Years: "<< "30 " << "Years" <<endl;
  cout << "Monthly Payment: " <<"$"<< t <<endl; 

  fout << "Mortgage Amount: "<<"$"<< p <<endl;
  fout << "Interest Rate: "<< r <<"%"<<endl;
  fout << "Term Years: "<< "30 " << "Years" <<endl;
  fout << "Monthly Payment: " <<"$"<< t <<endl;
  fout <<endl; 

  fout.close();
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Does `if (!getPassword())` even compile given that `getPassword` returns `void`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rather than use a void function for get password perhaps return a boolean value, true if the password was entered correctly (in the if statement) or false if 3 attempts failed (after the loop). Then in your main function deal with what getPassword returned as you need to.

so something like

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
#include <cmath>
bool getPassword() 
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
    string password; 
    cout << "Enter the password: "; 
    getline(cin, password); 

    if (password == "12345") return true; 
    cout << "INVALID. "; 
     } //for
return false;
} // getPassword 

int main ()
{
  if (!getPassword()) return 1;
  cout <<endl; 

  ofstream fout; 
  fout.open("mort.txt", ios::app);
  if (!fout.good()) throw "I/O error";

  double p; //Principal/Mortgage Amount
  cout << "What's the mortgage amount?";
  cin >> p; 
  cin.ignore (1000, 10);

  double r; 
  cout << "What's the annual interest rate?";
  cin >> r ;
  cin.ignore (1000, 10);
  double a = r / 100;
  double i = a / 12;

  double n = 30 * 12; //Number of payments per month
  double t = (p*(pow (1+i, n))*i) / ((pow(1+i, n)) -1);// monthly payment formula 

  cout<< fixed;
  cout<< setprecision(2);


  cout << "Mortgage Amount: "<<"$"<< p <<endl;
  cout << "Interest Rate: "<< r <<"%"<<endl;
  cout << "Term Years: "<< "30 " << "Years" <<endl;
  cout << "Monthly Payment: " <<"$"<< t <<endl; 


  fout << "Mortgage Amount: "<<"$"<< p <<endl;
  fout << "Interest Rate: "<< r <<"%"<<endl;
  fout << "Term Years: "<< "30 " << "Years" <<endl;
  fout << "Monthly Payment: " <<"$"<< t <<endl;
  fout <<endl; 

  fout.close();
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Are there any other options beside the bool?

Comment: you could use an integer as well if that's what you mean. or you could call exit(1) in the getPassword function but that is a little untidy in this case.

Comment: @David there are other options. But that's like having a piece of paper and scissors and saying "I want to cut this paper. I have a tool designed for doing so, but I'd like other options." :-) I would use bool unless you had some compelling reason not to.

Comment: we have not gotten to that in my programming book yet. I don't want to get docked points for it.

Comment: @David: you can simply use an `int`, returning 1 for "password accepted" and 0 for "wrong password three times".

Comment: @David: smitec has already written more in his answer than is generally appropriate for a homework question. Please try to extrapolate from his very comprehensive answer, and work out an acceptable solution from that. :-)