# Limit Login Attempts in C++

Tags: c++

Ok, I've been learning C++ for about 4 days now and it's my first programming language. So what this really means is that I've only got about 8 hours of programming experience and a lot of that was reading the intro to my C++ book and figuring out how to use XCode.

Anyway, my beginner C++ book is asking me to do the following: "Write a password prompt that gives a user only a certain number of password entry attempts so that the user cannot easily write a password cracker."

The only thing is I just now learned loops and I don't think the book has even covered how to limit attempts yet. Can anyone help? I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439004/c-password-attempt-limit), but it's too advanced for me and I don't get it. Here's the code: (really basic newb code... sorry if it insults your intelligence)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
string username;
string password;

while ( 1 )
{
    cout << "Enter your username: " << endl;
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Enter your password: " << endl;
    cin >> password;

    if ( username != "billy" && password != "bob" )
    {
        cout << "Incorrect username/password combination. Please try again." << "\n" <<
        endl;
    }

    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

cout << "Access granted." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Just so it's said...limited logins here wouldn't thwart a password cracker in the least.  You could just start up the program every X attempts.  :)

Comment: Try creating a new counting-variable and incrementing it whenever a wrong username/password is entered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `while ( 1 ) { }` construct repeats whatever is inside the `{}` to infinity, unless you explicitly `break` from the loop. That's a loop, btw.

How could you break from it after a number of attempts? You could have a counter that gets incremented with every attempt and break from the loop at the limit:

```
if ( ++counter >= limit )
    break;
```

or simply move the condition inside the while

```
while ( ++counter < limit )
```

or use a simple `for` loop or a `do {} while()`.

Answer (score 0):

Take some variable, say attemptCount, which keeps track of number of attempts made. Initialize it to 0 and increment it by 1 with every unsuccessful attempt. Put the condition in while loop checking that the attemptCount is less than the number of allowed attempts (taken 3 in my code below). So, the code will be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
string username;
string password;
int attemptCount = 0;

while ( attemptCount < 3 )
{
cout << "Enter your username: " << endl;
cin >> username;
cout << "Enter your password: " << endl;
cin >> password;

if ( username != "billy" && password != "bob" )
{
    cout << "Incorrect username/password combination. Please try again." << "\n" <<
    endl;

    attemptCount++;
}

else
{
    break;
}
}

cout << "Access granted." << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while(1)` loop will go on forever unless you also have some counter that you increment with every failed attempt.

But frankly...why have a `while` loop and a separate counter?  You have a known max number of iterations; that's the kind of case a `for` loop was made for.

```
for (int attempts = 1; attempts <= 3; ++attempts) {
    ... get login info ...

    if (...username and password are correct...) {
        cout << "Access granted.\n";
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Invalid login.\n";
    }
}

// Note as well, the default case (what happens if they make it through the loop)
// should be no access.  Otherwise, someone could just succeed by inputting three
// bad passwords.  :P
cout << "Too many invalid login attempts.\nExiting.\n";
return -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about how this works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  const int MAXTRYS = 4;
  int numTrys = 0;

  while(numTrys != MAXTRYS)
  {
    cout << "Attempting login" << endl;
    ++numTrys;
  }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `for` loop, not a `while` loop then. Something along the lines of:

```
bool bSuccess = false;
for (int i = 0 ; i < maxAttemps ; ++i)
{
    // your stuff
    // set bSuccess = true when relevant
}

if (bSuccess)
{
    // ok, successfully logged in
}
```

Infinite loops are often restricted to really infinite loops (waiting for network messages forever until quit, etc.). As a rule of thumb for good practice, try to avoid infinite loops as much as possible, and `break` constructs too because it's kind of hacky generally. To exercise, you should try to write nice code which translates to an easy dataflow.

I guess you suspect it, but this wouldn't be secure at all (you store username and password in plain text in the code of your executable).

Answer (score 0):

I`m having a hard time re-familiarizing with C++, since highschool ( @8 years ago ) alot has changed, or my informathics teacher was just bad...
I also find the "for" loop better for this kind of exercise but isn't it true that "return 0;" and "break;" do the same thing?
This is what I worked out with what I saw here and what I already "knew" :). Works like a charm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
int attempts = 0;
string password;

for (int attempts = 0; attempts < 5; ++attempts )
{
    cout << "enter your password! \n";
    cin >> password;
    ++attempts;
    if ( password == "boo123" )
    {
        cout << "granted!";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "denied! \n";
    }
}

}
```

and 1 more thing: all loops are infinite 'till you "break;" it or "return 0;" it...

Comment: No, `return 0;` returns from the function -- since this is main, it ends the program.  Whereas `break;` simply skips to the end of the current loop/switch structure.  In this particular case you get the same result, but if you wanted to do anything else in the program, you would need to use break instead of return.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Write a password prompt that gives a user only a certain number of password entry attempts—
so that the user cannot easily write a password cracker*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string password;
    int x = 1;

    while (1)  //This creates an overall top level infinite loop
    {
        cout << "Input password here: ";
        cin >> password;

       if ( password == "teddy") //This sets the condition for success
       {
           cout << "Access Granted!!!!";
           break; //The break is applied here to stop the cycle after success is made
       }

       else if ( password != "teddy") //This sets the condition for failure

       {
       cout << "Wrong username/password" << "\n" << x << " " << "wrong attempts" << "\n";
       ++x;

       if ( x > 5 ) // This is the counter limit portion. Limit set to 5 attempts

       {
           break;
       }

       }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string password;
    int pCounter = 0;
    cout << "Enter Password here: ";
    getline(cin, password);
    while(pCounter <= 4){
        if(password != "winner"){
            cout << "Count: " << pCounter << endl;
            cout << "Try again..wrong entry.." << endl;
            cout << "Enter Password here: ";
            getline(cin, password);
            ++pCounter;
                if((password != "winner") && (pCounter == 4)){
                    cout << "The End..No more tries!!" << endl;
                    break;
                }
        }

        else{
            cout << "Welcome In Bro" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another way of writing it with a while loop

Answer (score 0):

## include

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string password = "set";                                //declaring the password
    string input;                                           //declaring a string for input later

```
for (int attempt = 1; attempt <= 3; attempt++) {        //if you fail the password 3 times you get kicked out
    cout << "enter password " << flush;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == password) {                            //checks to make sure the user input matches set password
        cout << "granted";
        return 0;                                       //once correct password is put in the program ends
    }
    else {                                              //if password is wrong repeat till right or 3 trys
        cout << "you fail" << endl;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

int main()
{

```
string pass;
string user;



for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
    if (user == "malakas" && pass == "malakas1") {
        cout << " Access " << endl;
        return 0;

    }
    else if (user != "malakas" && pass == "malakas1" && i <= 5) {
        cout << "wrong user " << i << " tries left " << endl;
        cout << "Enter user" << endl;
        cin >> user;
       
    }
    else if (user == "malakas" && pass != "malakas1" && i <= 5) {
        cout << "wrong pass " << i << " tries left " << endl;
        cout << "Enter pass" << endl;
        cin >> pass;
    }
    else if (user != "malakas" && pass != "malakas1" && i <= 5) {
        cout << "wrong user and pass " << i << " tries left" << endl;
        cout << "Enter user" << endl;
        cin >> user;
        cout << "Enter pass" << endl;
        cin >> pass;
    } cout << " Contact admin" << endl;
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).